# How to fix BeanInstantiationException?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm writing an application with Spring Boot and I have a problem, I tried searching for solutions on the internet but failed. Anyone can help me This is my code, thank you very much.

**FTPController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api/files")
public class FTPController {

    public FTPController(StorageService _storageService) {
        _storageService.init();
    }

}
```

**StorageService.java**

```
public interface StorageService {
    void init();
}
```

**StorageServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class StorageServiceImpl implements StorageService {

    private Path location; 

    public StorageServiceImpl() {
        location = Paths.get(PathUtil.getPathUpload());
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(location);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileException("Could not initialize storage", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**PathUtil.java**

```
public class PathUtil {

    //private static final String USER_DIR = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    private static final String USER_DIR = Constants.getUserDir();

    private static final String PATH_RESOURCES = USER_DIR + "/src/main/resources/";

    public static String getPathUpload() {
        return PATH_RESOURCES + "upload";
    }

}
```

**Constants.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:config.properties"})
public class Constants implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static Environment env;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        Constants.env = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    public static String getUserDir() {
        return env.getProperty("USER_DIR");
    }

}
```

**config.properties**

```
USER_DIR=user.dir
```

**Log**

```
13:53:48.146 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'FTPController' defined in file [D:\Git\java\Boot\target\classes\com\spring\controller\FTPController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Git\java\Boot\target\classes\com\spring\service\impl\StorageServiceImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.spring.service.impl.StorageServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.spring.BootApplication.main(BootApplication.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Git\java\Boot\target\classes\com\spring\service\impl\StorageServiceImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.spring.service.impl.StorageServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.spring.service.impl.StorageServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.spring.service.impl.StorageServiceImpl.<init>(StorageServiceImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.spring.util.Constants.getUserDir(Constants.java:52)
    at com.spring.util.PathUtil.<clinit>(PathUtil.java:7)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Sorry becaue my english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `setEnvironment` is not getting called.

To fix this either

**Option 1:** Move `Constants.java` to `com.spring` package

OR

**Option 2:** Add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.spring.util" })` in `BootApplication`